# Jetty client POST file to Jetty Server

Tags: jetty

I'm creating a Jetty client that will POST files to a Jetty Server.  I'm trying to use the `ContentExchange.setFileForUpload()`, but I'm not able to find any example code on the web on how to use this API properly.

Answer (score 4):

The API is self-explanatory, just pass in the file that you want to upload; the rest is just basic HTTP:

```java
HttpClient httpClient = ...;

File file = ...;

ContentExchange exchange = new ContentExchange(true);
exchange.setURL("http://host/path");
exchange.setMethod(HttpMethods.POST);
exchange.setFileForUpload(file);
exchange.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
exchange.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
httpClient.send(exchange);

// Wait for the upload to complete
exchange.waitForDone();
```

Look at the [HttpClient documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/HttpClient) if you want better control on the HTTP phases the file upload will go through, or better yet switch to [Jetty 9's HttpClient](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/http-client.html), which is a [vastly improved](http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/11/the-new-jetty-9-http-client/) implementation.